# How does LINQ's left-join `join ... into` and `DefaultIfEmpty()` work?

Tags: c#, linq

How does LINQ's `join ... into` and `.DefaultIfEmpty()` work to express a left-join?

Does `.DefaultIfEmpty()` get evaluated just once, or *n* times?

Comment: How is `DefaultIfEmpty` unintuitive?  It returns a default value if the collection is empty, or just the original collection if it's not.  It's a way of ensuring that the resulting sequence is not empty.  It's called on every single sequence in the join operation, it just doesn't do much of anything whenever the input sequence has at least one value.  Perhaps you should write it out in method syntax rather than query syntax; sometimes that's easier for people to understand.

Comment: Are you asking what the implementation of group join is in LINQ-to-objects? Or how a group join is translated into method calls?  Or what? I'm having some difficulty figuring out what the question really is here.

Comment: @EricLippert - well I was thinking of Linq-to-objects first.  But now that you ask, I'd be interested in knowing how the answer changes for linq IQueryProviders.

Comment: Related post - [Why is DefaultIfEmpty implemented this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37118278/465053)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about LINQ to Objects, `DefaultIfEmpty` will be evaluated once per element in the result. It will be evaluated on the sequence which is the group of values matching the "left" part of the join. So if we have:

```
from x in foo
join y in bar into z
let g = z.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { x, g.Count() }
```

then for each `x` value, there will be an invocation of `DefaultIfEmpty`. For non-empty sequences, that will just pass values through. For empty sequences, the default value is returned (once) instead.

See [my Edulinq blog post on it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-12-defaultifempty.aspx) for more information.