# Why is DefaultIfEmpty implemented this way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Chasing the implementation of `System.Linq.Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty` took me to this method. It looks alright except for the following quaint details:

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(Enumerable.<DefaultIfEmptyIterator>d__90<>))]
private static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmptyIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            do
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
            while (enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
        else
        {
            yield return defaultValue;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = null;
    yield break;
    yield break;
}
```

1) Why does the code have to iterate over the whole sequence once it has been established that the sequence is not empty?

2) Why the yield break two times at the end?

3) Why explicitly set the `enumerator` to null at the end when there is no other reference to it?

I would have left it at this:

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(Enumerable.<DefaultIfEmptyIterator>d__90<>))]
private static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmptyIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            do
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
            // while (enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
        else
        {
            yield return defaultValue;
        }
    }
    // IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = null;
    yield break;
    // yield break;
}
```

Comment: [This source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1ff6169a97a478bf,references) looks different. Don't trust your decompiler, look at the original source code.

Comment: Thank you. Now only the first of the three questions remains.

Comment: The first question is easy: because `DefaultIfEmpty` has one purpose: return the whole sequence or a default value if it's empty. But it's implemented using deferred execution, you could write: `strings.Where(somecondition).DefaultIfEmpty("foo").First()` and the sequence will not be enumerated fully but only until the first element was yielded.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That's a `do while` loop. I was not seeing 20-20. I thought it was an independent `while` loop that followed a single `yield return` statement.

Comment: The double yield break is just a decompiler issue. Even if it was present in the source code it would do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` needs to act as the following:

1. If the source enumerable has no entries, it needs to act as an enumerable with a single value; the default value.
2. If the source enumerable is not empty, it needs to act as the source enumerable. Therefore, it needs to yield all values.

Comment: Thank you. Beside not seeing the code well as described in the comments to the question, I also had this misunderstanding, which your answer cleared up, that the implementation is supposed to return *the first element if the sequence is not empty*, which, thinking some more, doesn't seem to make any sense at all. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. That would be more like the `FirstOrDefault` method.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: understood the method as a protection against an empty sequence which might cause chained methods to fail, f.e. `First` throws an `InvalidOperationException` in that case. After `DefaultIfEmpty` you can use it safely. The overload enables you to provide a custom fallback value for an empty sequence.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for articulating it so well. I was thinking, "how do I respond to this without saying 'yeah, I know, but I was thinking...'." You've said it well.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you start enumerating and this code is used as another level of enumeration you have to enumerate the whole thing.

If you just `yield return` the first one and stop there the code using this enumerator will think there is only one value. So you have to enumerate everything there is and `yield return` it forward.

You could of course do `return enumerator` and that would work, but not after the `MoveNext()` has been called since that would cause the first value to be skipped. If there was another way to check if values exist then this would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the code have to iterate over the whole sequence once it has been established that the sequence is not empty?

As you can read in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/bb360179(v=vs.105).aspx) about `DefaultIfEmtpy` return value:

> An `IEnumerable<T>` object that contains the default value for the `TSource` type if source is empty; otherwise, source.

So, if the enumerable is empty the result is a enumerable containing the default value, but if the enumerable isn't empty the same enumerable is returned (not only the first element).

It may seem that this method is about checking only whether an enumerable contains elements or not, but it is not the case.

> Why the yield break two times at the end?

No ideas :)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)